# Pandas -- rank in different orders with a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I want to rank by the Group variable. For Group A, I want to rank in ascending order; for Group B, I want to rank in descending order. I only know how to rank the group by one order, such as the code below. Is there a way to rank a group in different orders within the group?

This is the sample data:

```
Group   Student Score
A      Jamie    1
A       Jack    2
A      James    3
B      Jamie    1
B       Jack    2
B      James    3
```

This is the desired outcome

```
 Group  Student Score   rank
   A    Jamie   1   1
   A    Jack    2   2
   A    James   3   3
   B    Jamie   1   3
   B    Jack    2   2
   B    James   3   1
```

This is what I tried:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Group')['Score'].rank(ascending=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that I can think of is by defining a custom list defining the order for each group, and apply the same logic using a list comprehension iterating over `rank_ascending`:

```
rank_ascending = [True, False]
df['rank'] = pd.concat([g.Score.rank(ascending=asc) for asc, (_,g) in 
                        zip(rank_ascending, df.groupby('Group'))], 0)
```

---

```
print(df)

  Group Student  Score  rank
0     A   Jamie      1   1.0
1     A    Jack      2   2.0
2     A   James      3   3.0
3     B   Jamie      1   3.0
4     B    Jack      2   2.0
5     B   James      3   1.0
```

---

Update - for an easier to read version:

```
order = [True, False]
ranked_groups = []
for asc, (_,g) in zip(order, df.groupby('Group')):
    ranked_groups.append(g.Score.rank(ascending=asc))

df['rank'] = pd.concat(ranked_groups, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please unpack the code a little more? Also, I got an error "No objects to concatenate"

Comment: Sure, let me know if the update works @warrior You have to make sure to have as many `order` values as groups in the `Group` column